# Implementing Indexer from C# in Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, indexer

Within C# there're these things called **indexers** that do something similar to this:

```
public Something
{
     public Object this[String s]
     {
           // do something with s
           return something;
     }
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
Something instance = new Something();
Object obj = instance["banana's"];
```

I'm just wondering if it's possible to have something like this implemented in AS3 where you use the square brackets, or do I require a function to do this?

Comment: Are you looking to do something like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zfS2Yv88) or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something similar by extending flash.utils.Proxy.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html

But it's not quite the same or as flexible as the C# option.